# Fuzzy Compare between two hive columns using apache spark with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fuzzy, fuzzywuzzy

I am reading the data from 2 hive tables. Token table has the tokens that needs to be matched with the input data. Input data will have description column along with other columns. I need to split input data and need to compare each splitted element with all the elements from the token table.
currently I am using me.xdrop.fuzzywuzzy.FuzzySearch  library for fuzzy match.

below is my code snippet-

```
val tokens = sqlContext.sql("select token from tokens")
val desc = sqlContext.sql("select description from desceriptiontable")
val desc_tokens = desc.flatMap(_.toString().split(" "))
```

Now i need to iterate desc_tokens and each element of desc_tokens should be fuzzy matched with each element of tokens and it it exceeds 85% match i need to replace element from desc_tokens by element from the tokens.

Example --

My token list is

```
hello
this
is
token
file
sample
```

and my input description is

```
helo this is input desc sampl
```

code should return

```
hello this is input desc sample
```

as **hello** and **helo** are fuzzy matched > 85% so helo will be replaced by hello. Similarly for sampl.

Answer (score 0):

I make a test with this library : https://github.com/rockymadden/stringmetric

Other idea (Not optimized) :

```
//I change order tokens
val tokens = Array("this","is","sample","token","file","hello");
val desc_tokens = Array("helo","this","is","token","file","sampl");

val res = desc_tokens.map(str => {
  //Compute score beetween tokens and desc_tokens
  val elem = tokens.zipWithIndex.map{ case(tok,index) => (tok,index,JaroMetric.compare(str, tok).get)}
  //Get token has max score
  val emax = elem.maxBy{case(_,_,score) => score}
  //if emax have a score > 0.85 get It. Else keep input
  if(emax._3 > 0.85) tokens(emax._2) else str

})
res.foreach { println }
```

My Output :

`hello
this
is
token
file
sample`

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy for the reply. zipWithIndex would traverse index wise. So if hello token is present at index 2 or 3 this code would not work.
What I am looking for is each token from input description should look for all the tokens from token list and return token from token list which is best match or first match (>85%)